# cofiguration export flash animation to display in cell phone

Tags: flash, export, flv

I am a beginner in flash cs6. I make an animation with some movieclipe and sound and text.
I have not script (i use only stop()) in my file.
how can I display my file in cell phone?
what format is good?
what is configuration?
 i convert .swf to  .flv with some software but result have problem. new flv file is shorter than .swf file. and don't show texts

Comment: Not **FLV** use **MP4** for mobiles. Choose "baseline" profile when using the video converter software (it's an expected option for all MP4 saving). Set audio codec to AAC. Make sure all your animation frames are in one long (continous) timeline. Text boxes must be type **Static** (not **Dynamic** or **User Input**). Sound must be on timeline also (on  new layer). Also no **Scenes** or animations within other **MovieClips**. Everything must play from frame 1 to ending. This is what external software converts to video frames

Answer (score 0):

When you click Publish, look for the "Target" field and select Air for Android/iOS.. you can export your animation as an .apk capable of running on android devices or the ios equivalent which you can then run on your device.

Comment: my work is a animation it is not a game or progrma. apk format is good format?

Comment: @andygoestohollywood.. Youtube doesnt make viwewers install an APK for every video so why should she make users install an APK everytime she has a new animation???